# Async function returns [object Promise] instead of the real value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to ReactJS.

I have some problem with the return value of **async function**

when I call

```
const result = this.getFieldsAPI();
```

the **result** value is [object Promise]

I see [object Promise] from **console.log("result : " + result);**

```
getFieldsAPI = async() => {
    let currentChromosome = "";
    switch (this.state.chromosome) {
      case "Autosom":
        currentChromosome = "/getlocusautosomalkit/";
        break;
      case "Y_STRs":
        currentChromosome = "/getlocusykit/";
        break;
      case "X_STRs":
        currentChromosome = "/getlocusxkit/";
        break;
      default:
        currentChromosome = "";
    }
    let result = [];
    await Axios.get(API_URL + currentChromosome + this.state.currentKit).then((Response) => {
      Response.data.map((locus) => {
        result.push(locus);
      });
    })
    return "result";
  }

  // To generate mock Form.Item
  getFields() {
    const count = this.state.expand ? 10 : 6;
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const children = [];
    const result = this.getFieldsAPI();
    console.log("result : " + result);
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      children.push(
        <Col span={8} key={i} style={{ display: i < count ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
          <Form.Item label={`Field ${i}`}>
            {getFieldDecorator(`field-${i}`, {
              rules: [{
                required: true,
                message: 'Input something!',
              }],
            })(
              <Input placeholder="placeholder" />
            )}
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
      );
    }
    return children;
  }
```

Comment: if you want to have the real return value, use `const result = await this.getFieldsAPI();`

Comment: So, you're saying an async function is returning a promise? I see no problems with that. that's what they do.

Comment: but if I added async to in front of getField() It will throw the errors.

Comment: I think you're remote call is simply in a place it shouldn't be. That isn't something you generally want to be running every time a render occurs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not waiting for the value of `result` so you just get an unfulfilled promise. If you change

```
const result = this.getFieldsAPI();
```

to

```
const result = await this.getFieldsAPI();
```

You'll get what you're after. You'll also need to make `getFields()` async.

Comment: if I make getField() as async. it will throw errors.
**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Answer (score 7):

Async functions would always return a `Promise`. Promises may be resolved or rejected. You can handle promises in the following ways:

1. Using `then` :

```js
this.getFieldsAPI.then((value) => {
  // code on success
}, (errorReason) => {
  // code on error
});
```

2. Using `await`:

```js
try { 
  const result = await this.getFieldsAPI();
} catch(errorReason) { 
  // code on error
}
```

You may choose on what fits you best. I personally prefer option 2, which seems less confusing.

Comment: ... but thanks for offering option 1, which suited my situation better

Answer (score 3):

To get a valid response you should adjust your code a bit, because currently you're returning the string "result" and not the array from your promise.

In your `getFieldsApi` method you can do following:

```
...
Response = await Axios.get(API_URL + currentChromosome + this.state.currentKit);
return Response.data.map((locus) => locus);
```

And you would call it like:

```
const result = await this.getFieldsApi();
```

Comment: if I make getField() as async. it will throw errors. **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**
Is there another way to achieve it and keep getField() as a normal function.

Comment: How and where do you call `getField`?